# Maven release:branch

Tags: maven

I have a maven multi module project.

When the code is development complete, we would want to write a branch build job in Jenkins which branches the code, increment the pom versions in the trunk, and remove the
-SNAPSHOT from the pom versions in the branch.

So, if the trunk is 2.2-SNAPSHOT, by the end of the operation, the trunk should be 2.3-SNAPSHOT, and the newly created branch should have poms with 2.2.

When I use release:branch the trunk is getting updated but it's not removing the -SNAPSHOT from the poms in the branch.

Please let me know if you have any ideas of achieving this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suspect that your best bet is to take the release plugin source code and write your own variant. I did something similar in Python, but it proved to be quite a mess.

Answer (score 2):

From [Maven Release plugin: Create a branch](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/examples/branch.html)

> By default, the POM in the new branch keeps the same version as the local working copy, and the local POM is incremented to the next revision. If you want to update versions in the new branch and not in the working copy, run:
>
> mvn release:branch -DbranchName=my-branch -DupdateBranchVersions=true -DupdateWorkingCopyVersions=false
>
> Note: This can be useful if you want to create a branch from a tag

As an alternative, you might want to try the [Versions Maven plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin):

> mvn versions:set versions:commit -DnewVersion=2.2.0

You would still need to create the branch by hand though...

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Is there a property to set the branch version number along with -DupdateBranchVersions=true in the command itself? I did tried to use -Dproject.rel.groupid:artifactid=2.2, but that didnt seem to work.

Comment: Did you add --batch-mode and the -Dupdate* parameters? Maybe you should post the full command-line you used (possibly anonimized)?

Comment: This is the command that I am giving in Jenkins:                    --batch-mode release:clean release:branch -DbranchName=2.2 -DupdateBranchVersions=true 
-Dproject.rel.groupid:artifactid=2.2                                -DupdateVersionsToSnapshot=false -DautoVersionSubmodules=true       I also tried using release:clean release:branch -DbranchName=2.2 -DautoVersionSubmodules=true 
-DupdateBranchVersions=true -DreleaseVersion=2.2 -DupdateVersionsToSnapshot=false

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help any further as I can't test this right now...

Stuff like this is why I do my branching by hand and use the Versions maven plugin.

Comment: I too wanted to be able to create a branch and not have to do it by hand. Still no way to solve this?